# Showing that a function $f' \not \in L_1([0,1])$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to find a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous on $[0,1]$
such that it is differentiable a.e on [0,1] and $f' \not \in L_1([0,1])$.

I'm trying to use
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^2sin(1/x^2) &\mbox{if }0<x\leq1 ,\\0&\mbox{if x=0}\end{array}\right.$$

so
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2x\cdot sin(1/x^2) - \frac{2cos(1/x^2)}{x} &\mbox{if }0<x\leq1 ,\\0&\mbox{if x=0}\end{array}\right.$$

but I'm really having trouble proving that $$\int_{0}^1 |f'(x)|$$ diverges

Comment: The substitution $u=\frac1{x^2}$, $du=-2u^{3/2}\,dx$ yields
$$
\int^\infty_1\left|\frac{\sin u}{u^2}-\frac{\cos u}{u}\right|\,du
$$ The function $u\mapsto\frac{\cos u}{u}$ is not integrable over $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint 1*. Notice that $f \in L \iff |f| \in L$.

*Hint 2*. Try to draw the plot of the $f(x)$. What can you say about convergence of some series after that?